# Spinnaker - Configuring Redis for scale of execution history & caching

Tags: redis, spinnaker

Is there an opinionated way to setup Redis for Spinnaker caching and execution history?  My team has been running Spinnaker on k8s on prem with a single Redis instance for a while.  As our Spinnaker installation grows, we have been hitting issues with Redis connection issues as well as memory/disk consumption.  We are looking to revamp that storage to avoid these issues.  I have heard that Netflix has a combination of read only and read/write clusters of Redis nodes for different Spinnaker services.  Is there any documentation around this or can anyone provide details on a successful scaled setup?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MySQL DB instance for Orca to persist the execution and history. 
You can also enable [dual mode](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/operator/orca-redis-to-sql/) first to work alongside your Redis Instance.